# Question regarding the convergence properties of the Fourier summation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-series

I've seen a lot of proofs of the convergence properties for the Fourier series of continuous periodic functions that use the assumption that the function's derivative and second derivatives exist and are also continuous. I was wondering is the stipulation that the derivatives exist considered not that restrictive of an assumption because we can consider the Stone-Wierstrass polynomial approximation of the function instead which converges uniformly to any continuous function on an interval and does have continuous derivatives?

Comment: For Fourier series of continuous functions there are examples where they diverge on fairly large sets - sets of divergence need to have measure zero but otherwise can be fairly arbitrary; so some condition on the function is necessary; this being said, the Caesaro means of the Fourier series always converge uniformly for continuous functions so those work

Comment: Although polynomials $p_n$ converge uniformly to the required continuous function $f$, derivatives of polynomials $p_n'(x)$ need not converge. If it does then the limit is differentiable and derivative $f'(x)$ given by limit of derivative of polynomials $\lim_n p_n'(x)$ by uniform convergence.

Comment: Wow weird, and thanks.

Comment: Let $f $be a continuous real function with period $2\pi$ and let $F_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n A_j\cos jx +B_j\sin jx$ be the $n-$th partial sum of the Fourier series for $f$. Theorem (Fejer): $G_m(x)=\frac  {1}{m+1}\sum_{n=0}^m F_n(x)$ converges uniformly to f$f$ Note that $(G_m)_m$ is generally not the Fourier series for $f$.

Comment: Whoa I've never seen that Gm. That's pretty cool, thanks!